Setting 3840x1080 (32:9) monitor on Ubuntu 24.04.1
The max resolution I can choose in my Lenovo T14 is 3840x2160(16:9). I have followed these  steps (that appear in all the websites that I have found) to try to set up the resolution that I need
gtf 3840 1080 60
xrandr --newmode "3840x1080_60.00"  345.60  3840 4080 4496 5152  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 3840x1080_60.00
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 3840x1080_60.00

but I get this error message
  Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x600
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  29

The new mode 3840x1080_60.00 is listed when I run xrandr, but it is not listed under settings -> displays. I checked the resolution of the graphic card in my laptop (see below) and that looks ok.
Any help is very appreciated?


I have not heard of gtf before I have always used cvt. You could try cvt 3840 1080 60 to generate your modeline as for whatever reason it generates a slightly different modeline. Also, xrandr commands should work under Xorg/X11 but now the default in Ubuntu is Wayland and not sure if they work under Wayland? Not saying they don't, I don't know as I only use Xorg/X11. But you can choose between the two when you login to Ubuntu by clicking the cog icon and selecting.
